# How do I bind this JSON data to a Kendo UI Chart?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm having an extremely difficult time binding JSON data to Kendo UI charts in ASP.Net MVC. I've been going over documentation, taking apart demos, searching through everything I can find here on SO (and elsewhere) to try and find a clue to what I'm doing wrong that can put me back on track, but I keep hitting a brick wall. I'm starting to worry that I'm just dense, haha.

Here is what I'm working with so far:

The JSON data:

```
{  
   "responseHeader":{  
      "status":0,
      "QTime":6,
      "params":{  
         "indent":"true",
         "q":"*:*",
         "wt":"json"
      }
   },
   "response":{  
      "numFound":5,
      "start":0,
      "docs":[  
         {  
            "monthAndYear":"Apr 2015",
            "region":"Central Region",
            "projects_finalized":3,
            "_version_":1497873686497067008
         },
         {  
            "monthAndYear":"Apr 2015",
            "region":"Northern Region",
            "projects_finalized"1,
            "_version_":1497873686498115584
         },
         {  
            "monthAndYear":"Apr 2015",
            "region":"Eastern Region",
            "projects_finalized":1,
            "_version_":1497873686498115585
         },
         {  
            "monthAndYear":"Apr 2015",
            "region":"Southern Region",
            "projects_finalized":6,
            "_version_":1497873686498115586
         },
         {  
            "monthAndYear":"Apr 2015",
            "region":"Western Region",
            "projects_finalized":2,
            "_version_":1497873686498115588
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's my Model:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Responseheader responseHeader { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Responseheader
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int QTime { get; set; }
    public Params _params { get; set; }
}

public class Params
{
    public string indent { get; set; }
    public string q { get; set; }
    public string wt { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int numFound { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public Doc[] docs { get; set; }
}

public class Doc
{
    public string monthAndYear { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public int projects_finalized { get; set; }
    public long _version_ { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Project Chart";
}

<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 2em; width: 1000px; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<ProjectChart.Models.ProjectClass>()
    .Name("barProjectsThisMonth")
    .Title("Project Results")
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(false)
    )
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
        .Background("transparent")
    )
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("ProjectClass", "HomeController")))
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Bar(model => model.response.docs.projects_finalized).Name("Total Projects Completed")
              .Labels(labels => labels.Background("transparent").Visible(true));
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                .Categories(model => model.response.docs.region)
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis
        .Numeric()
        .MajorUnit(2)
        .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
    )
    .Theme("MaterialBlack")
)
</div>
```

Here's my Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DataBinding()
    {
        string url = "https://solr.fakeURL.com/json";
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        var json = c.DownloadString(url);

        return Json(json);
    }
}
```

For clarity, I can't make any changes to the output of the JSON. I have to work with what's given.

Comment: First of all your model is not 100% valid: `params` JSON property will not be parsed because C# property is `_params`. You should rename it to `@params`. The controller method you provided just returns empty view, but in your view example you are using model property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kendo Chart doesn't just accept any JSON data, it's essential that this is in the correct format, generally using `return Json(chartModel);` you don't need to worry about this too much.

In my opinion it's also bad design to be tightly coupling your chart to your data source (the web service) like this, but that's not that relevant for your current issue.

Anyway, I'd do the following:

In your business/data access layer, where you call the web service to get the JSON, convert the JSON into CLR objects. You can use Json.Net for this.

```
Rootobject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);
```

Once you've converted the JSON, get from the data what your chart needs to show (just `projects_finalized` maybe?) and return this to your chart.

Something like this:

```
public class ChartModel
{
    public string region { get; set; }
    public int projects_finalized { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DataBinding()
{
    IEnumerable<ChartModel> result = GetData();
    return Json(result);
}

public IEnumerable<ChartModel> GetData() {
    string url = "https://solr.fakeURL.com/json";
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    var json = c.DownloadString(url);

    // Do something like this to deserialize the JSON.
    Rootobject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);

    // Here you flatten root object into collection of `ChartModel` objects

    return chartModels;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track. Sorry for taking so long to accept the answer.

Comment: @Nitroid No problem. Feel free to upvote my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could try an easier approach to get started, which is just pass list of docs to the view and let it bind at the client side

firstly, deserialize json into objects, in your case, 5 docs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
    var list = new List<Docs>();
    // deserialize json into list
    return View(list);
}
```

secondly, change the view, basically pass the datasource from constructor and turn off server operation as below.

```
@model List<Docs>
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<ProjectChart.Models.ProjectClass>(Model)
    .DataSource(d => d.ServerOperation(false))
```

you might have to tweak your view to get it working, but at least your data is there. good luck